# No beeps and no display when I power on PC

Tags: boot, memory, display, motherboard, power-supply

The fans are working.

There is no beep even in removing the RAM.

I tried everything that I found on the internet, but nothing worked for me.

Can anyone help me?

I have an Onboard video card. It's FOXCONN G31MX 2.0 Series motherboard.

Comment: How about the HDD read/write indicator on CPU ?

Answer (score 0):

Try disconnecting everything down to the basics. disconnect everything else just to eliminate any external hardware causing the issue.

If you don't see anything. Are there any beep codes being generated or is it silent with just the fan spinning up? 
If there's beep codes you should be able to diagnose the failing component. If no beep codes then it's pretty much PSU or Motherboard. PSU is easy to replace. The motherboard is obviously more of a pain.

Bulging capacitors is the kiss of death for most motherboards so definitely something to look for.

Second Which fan making the noise?? If it is PSU fan then I would bank on a PSU. If it is a CPU fan then you might have a bad CPU or Motherboard.

Comment: OP has already mentioned there are no beeps

Comment: Yup I know :) the beep not always work for some reason, by removing everything and replace it again sometimes the beep comes again

Comment: I have removed and replaced every things. but no beeps and display. any way thank you. :)